# Message payload is of type: String

Tags: mule, esb

I try to test Transforming Data in a Flow example in this page :
"http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transforming+Data+in+a+Flow"

but I get this error on browsers :
Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{HellowFlow1.commponent.30555765}. Message payload is of type: String

the exact message in console of mule studio  is this :

```
ERROR 2013-05-01 12:39:19,067 [[configureendpoint].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message : Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "NameTransformer{this=4146a7, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[]}" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: NameTransformer{this=4146a7, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[]} doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Found too many possible methods on object "org.mule.examples.hello.NameTransformer" that accept parameters "{class java.lang.String}", Methods matched are "[public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setMimeType(java.lang.String) throws javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException, public final java.lang.Object org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(java.lang.Object) throws org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException, public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setName(java.lang.String), public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setEncoding(java.lang.String)]"
]
Code : MULE_ERROR-321
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "NameTransformer{this=4146a7, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[]}" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: NameTransformer{this=4146a7, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[]} doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Found too many possible methods on object "org.mule.examples.hello.NameTransformer" that accept parameters "{class java.lang.String}", Methods matched are "[public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setMimeType(java.lang.String) throws javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException, public final java.lang.Object org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(java.lang.Object) throws org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException, public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setName(java.lang.String), public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setEncoding(java.lang.String)]"
] (org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException)
org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet:52 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/cur...)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException: Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "NameTransformer{this=4146a7, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[]}" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: NameTransformer{this=4146a7, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}, sourceTypes=[]} doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Found too many possible methods on object "org.mule.examples.hello.NameTransformer" that accept parameters "{class java.lang.String}", Methods matched are "[public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setMimeType(java.lang.String) throws javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException, public final java.lang.Object org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(java.lang.Object) throws org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException, public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setName(java.lang.String), public void org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.setEncoding(java.lang.String)]"
]
at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:52)
at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:343)
at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:86)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

If it is possible help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing your XML configuration so I'm forced to take a wild guess based on the exception I see: I bet you wrongly used a Java **Component** instead of a Java **Transformer** when you configured `org.mule.examples.hello.NameTransformer`.

Comment: When I read the OP, I knew it sounded familiar... I just couldn't put my finger on it. Now that you have brought it up, I would concur with your assessment.

Comment: thank u so much  its true i use component instead of java transformer